# How can I add a delay to a performSegue in my viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

In the viewDidLoad of my first viewController, if the user is authenticated 
is sent to the home automatically with a performSegue

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil{

            self.ballClipRotatePulse.startAnimating()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome1", sender: self)

        }
    }
}
```

but since I would like the users see a loading animation first, how can I do that the performSegue start two seconds later than  `self.ballClipRotatePulse.startAnimating()` ?

Comment: You can call `performSegue` in viewDidAppear and still want to delay then use timer

Comment: You can use dispatchQueue

Comment: can you help  me with an example guys, is the first time i tried to do something like this

Comment: Isn't there a notification or completion handler when the animation stops? Waiting a hard-coded time is always the worst solution/case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is simple:

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in
    if user != nil {
        self.ballClipRotatePulse.startAnimating()
        // to run something in 2 seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            // your code here
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome1", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.0 // 2 is desirable delay
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){ // your postponed code }
```

By the way, don't forget that some interface elements could be touched by user during the delay period and thus your app could behave unexpectedly. The better solution is to call `performSegue` from the animation completion handler.